# g++ and clang++ different behaviour for SFINAE external implementation

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, sfinae

Another question for C++ language layers.

With the following code I try to enable a method, `foo<T>::bar()`, only when `T` is a constant type and using a `using` alias type defined inside `foo<T>`, implementing it (when enabled) outside the body of the class/struct.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct foo
 {
   using cT = T const;

   template <typename U = T, 
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, cT>, int> = 0>
   void bar ();
 };

template <typename T>
template <typename U,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, typename foo<T>::cT>, int>>
void foo<T>::bar () // ......................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 { }                //                          wrong for g++

int main()
 {
 }
```

This code compile without problems with clang++ (HEAD 13.0.0, for example, but also older versions) but, with g++ (HEAD 12.0.0, for example, but also older versions) gives the following compilation error

```
prog.cc:16:6: error: no declaration matches 'void foo<T>::bar()'
   16 | void foo<T>::bar ()
      |      ^~~~~~
prog.cc:10:9: note: candidate is: 'template<class T> template<class U, typename std::enable_if<is_same_v<U, const T>, int>::type <anonymous> > void foo<T>::bar()'
   10 |    void bar ();
      |         ^~~
prog.cc:4:8: note: 'struct foo<T>' defined here
    4 | struct foo
      |        ^~~
```

It seems that the problem is the use of `typename foo<T>::cT` in the external implementation, that for clang++ matches the corresponding `cT` in the internal declaration, for g++ doesn't matches.

If you directly use `T const`, in the external implementation,

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<U, T const>, int>>
void foo<T>::bar () // ......................^^^^^^^
 { }                //         now compile with both g++ and clang++
```

The question, as usual, is: who's right? g++ or clang++?

Comment: This is part 2 of the linked target, where the member `cT` is not a template. There are unfortunately no answers yet (quoting the standard) that say whether the code is valid.

Comment: @cigien - I'm agree: it's almost your case 2, with a `using` instead of a variable.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think the difference between the member alias, and a member variable matters, since the diagnostic is the same in both cases. There only appears to be a  difference when the entity is a template or not.